# Enum как хранилище данных

Tags: java, enum

Имеется абстрактный класс `Measurments`. Все типы `Measurments` наследуют данный класс - `Temperature`, `Rainfall` и т.д. У каждого типа есть значение и единица измерения. Мне подсказали, что для всех типов единицы измерения нужно создать один `enum`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как должен выглядеть такой `enum` и как его связать с каждым классом, где единицы измерений (%, м/сек, мм/кв.м, ю/с/з/в и т.д.)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Хранение единиц измерений можно реализовать так:

```
public enum Unit {
    TEMP("C"),  // Температура
    WIND("м/сек"),  // Скорость ветра
    PREC("мм");  // Осадки

    private String unit;

    Unit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public String value() {
        return unit;
    }
}
```

Для направления ветра:

```
public enum WindDirection {
    NORTH("север"),
    EAST("восток"),
    ...;

    private String direction;

    Units(String direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public String value() {
         return direction;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
public class Wind extends Measurments {
    private static final String UNIT = Unit.WIND.value();

    private String value;
    private WindDirection direction;

    Wind(String value, WindDirection direction) {
        this.value = value;
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Ветер: " + 
               "скорость " + this.value + " " + UNIT + ", " +
               "направление " + this.direction.value();
    }
}
```

Таким образом `Unit` будет хранилищем для всех единиц измерений.

Comment: А как поступить с направлением ветра?
В anum будут EAST("восток"), WEST("запад") и т.д
Т,е в классе WindDirection единичей измерения может быть одной из 4-х направлений

Comment: Направление ветра не совсем единица измерений. Поэтому для него предлагаю написать отдельный `enum`. Правда как `static final` поле его уже нельзя будет использовать, так как в пределах одного класса у вас будет использоваться несколько значений из нового `enum`.

Comment: @АлександрДерменжи добавил в пример `WindDirection`